# Copy only part of row of sheet A if cell matches criteria, and copy to different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

This is the code I am currently using, it works perfectly but it's copying the whole row instead of just a portion to where I would like it to go. 
How do I specify the code to only copy a part of the row?
I commented the code where I think the issue is.
Any help would be very helpful!
P.S. I have put off posting this for a while as I thought this would have been addressed already but my searching found nothing.

```
Sub CopySPData()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Host New")

    j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("F1:F1000")   ' Do 1000 rows
        If c = "Host" Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j) ' I think the issue is in this line
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: look at the answers you got below and let us know if they worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just change `Rows()` for `Range()` which contain come part of row. For example, if you want only columns from **C** to **K** in `Source` sheet, and paste them into columns **E** to **M** in `Target` sheet, you need to change:

```
Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
```

to:

```
Source.Range("C" & c.Row & ":K" & c.Row).Copy Target.Range("E" & j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to copy the cells in column E to Column G where the value in column F of that row equals "Host", and paste it at "Host New" sheet, starting from Column A, you can use the line below:

```
Source.Range("E" & c.Row & ":G" & c.Row).Copy Target.Range("A" & j)
```

**Note**: you can use the `AutoFilter` method to copy the entire range at once, without the need to use the `For Each c In Source.Range("F1:F1000")` loop.

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks, that was helpful! The reason that I'm doing the loop is that I have 12 different names to search for through the primary list, and each need to be moved to different sheet. Do you think the Autofilter would still be best for that task?